# problem with saved username and passwords on register page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firefox

so i have a form for registering user

[image]

so when page loaded firefox automatically set values for inputs from saved logins

what can I do to prevent that?
this is a part of codes

```
                   <div className="input-group mb-3">
                     <input
                            id="nameInput"
                            ref={nameRef}
                            type="text"
                            className="form-control"
                            placeholder="نام و نام خانوادگی"
                            onChange={nameChangeHandler}
                        />
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the attribute `autocomplete="off"` to your form. However, different browsers may handle this differently.

```html
<form action="/login" autocomplete="off" >
  <input type="text" id="username" name="username" /><br />
  <input type="text" id="password" name="password" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

To disable the autocomplete for input fields, we need to set its `autoComplete` attribute to `off`.

```
<input
       autoComplete="off"
       id="nameInput"
       ref={nameRef}
       type="text"
       className="form-control"
       placeholder="نام و نام خانوادگی"
       onChange={nameChangeHandler}
                        />
```